# FFmpeg map optional (audio) stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I use this command to produce a file scaled and with an overlay image:

```
ffmpeg 
-i input.* -i overlay.png 
-filter_complex "[0:v]...; ...[1:v]overlay=... ... [resultingvideo]" 
-map "[resultingvideo]" -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 
-acodec libmp3lame -q:a 50 
outputfilename.mov
```

where "..." represents some left out filtering.

The problem is, there is no audio.

If I add `-map 0:a`, there is audio if the input has audio, and an error and no output file if the input has no audio.

**How can I get ffmpeg to optionally use the audio from the input if it exists, and otherwise ignore audio or produce silence or something?**

Or, do I have to analyze the file first using ffprobe before I can generate my script command?

Answer (score 7):

Recent versions of ffmpeg support a [conditional mapping option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Advanced-options):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map "0:a?" output.mp4
```

This will ignore non-existing audio streams in the input file.

Comment: `[0:a?]` how can I do something like this in `filter_complex`

Comment: I want to select other trace if the language I map are not exist  `-map "0:a:m:language:jpn`

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to run ffmpeg twice, you could first do the overlay then do a second command to copy that video and encode audio from the original. If the audio doesn't exist, ffmpeg will complain and do anything. If it's happy then you get the audio and video.

It would look something like this.

`ffmpeg 
-i input.* -i overlay.png 
-filter_complex "[0:v]...; ...[1:v]overlay=... ... [resultingvideo]" 
-map "[resultingvideo]" -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 
outputfilenameJustVideo.mov`

followed by

`ffmpeg -y
-i outputfilenameJustVideo.mov -i input.*

-acodec libmp3lame -q:a 50 -c:v copy -map 0:v -map 1:a
outputfilename.mov`

With my brief testing, ffmpeg did not want to create/override anything when there was no audio and did when there was audio.

To be clear, this is a hack. You would probably want to have some logic to rename the final product to whatever you wanted.

I do not know of a simple, one command method.