# Ignore audio stream if it is not found in filter_complex of ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am creating a video output using some overlays and scale layers through `filter_complex` of ffmpeg. I am using ffmpeg v3.3.2

I am using following command for videos with audio:

```
# avideo -> aoutput : 50% Faster
ffmpeg3 \
    -i avideo.wmv \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" \
    -map "[v]" \
    -map "[a]" \
    aoutput.wmv
```

I am using following command for videos without audio:

```
# video -> output : 50% Faster
ffmpeg3 \
    -i video.wmv \
    -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v]" \
    -map "[v]" \
    output.wmv
```

This works fine. But, I don't know if a video file has any audio streams in it or not. I need to make this command work for both of these scenarios.

I am trying to use following command for this:

```
# unknown(avideo, video) -> uoutput : 50% Faster
ffmpeg3 \
    -i video.wmv \
    -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" \
    -map "[v]" \
    -map "[a]" \
    uoutput.wmv
```

But, this fails because input video doesn't have any audio stream. Exact error message is

> Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a] matches no streams.

This question is most similar to my question: [FFmpeg map optional (audio) stream](https://superuser.com/questions/753703), except that they aren't using `filter_complex` to execute this optional scenario. So, [conditional mapping option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Advanced-options) wouldn't work for me.

How can I tell ffmpeg to use audio stream, in `filter_complex`, if there's any audio, otherwise ignore audio.

- I want to do this in a single command.
- I want to use ffmpeg alone (no ffprobe: size issues).

But, if you have any good options, please share them.

**Edit:**

I have updated my command with "-af atempo=2.0" and this seems to fix my issue. I do it like this.

```
ffmpeg3 \
    -i video.wmv \
    -af atempo=2.0 \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS" \
    uoutput.wmv
```

But, I am still open to more options. Above fix seems wrong. While this works for all formats, but fails for WMV of 30sec with a bug https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible hacks for this.

1) If you don't combine processed streams inside the filtergraph, then just use simple filterchains.

```
ffmpeg \
-i avideo.wmv \
-vf "setpts=0.5*PTS" \
-af "atempo=2.0" \
aoutput.wmv
```

The audio chain will only be parsed if an an audio output stream is present.

2) Add a dummy audio input and leave out the input label for the audio filtering. ffmpeg will pick the first available audio stream.

```
ffmpeg \
    -i video.wmv \
    -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];atempo=2.0[a]" \
    -map "[v]" \
    -map "[a]" \
    uoutput.wmv
```

I recommend you upgrade to ffmpeg 4.0 or later. There were some filtering bugs in 3.x series, since fixed.

Comment: i have 2 videos too be concat using ffmpeg in android. we dont know user will select mute video or video with sound. how can we concat e those videos? if videos has audio then its working fine but if one of them dont have audio stream then ffmpeg throws and error no matches stream